# how can i setting utf-8 from csv file to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I got some problems that my result not right (i think it's not UTF-8).

**This is input(CSV file)**

[image]

**This is output (in phpmyadmin)**

[image]

Please Help!

```
$file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  'upload/file_csv/'.$file_data['file_name'];
        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);

                foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                    $insert_data = array(                           
                        'firstname'=>$row['tea_name'],
                        'lastname'=>$row['tea_surename'],
                        'teacher_id'=>$row['teacher_id'],
                    );
                        $tea_id = $insert_data['teacher_id'];
                        $fname = $insert_data['firstname'];
                        $lname = $insert_data['lastname'];

                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($insert_data);$i++){
                            $sql = "select * from teacher where teacher_id = '$tea_id' ";                           
                            $result = $this->db->query($sql)->num_rows();
                        }

                        if($result>0){                              
                            $sql="UPDATE `dvp`.`teacher` SET `firstname` = '$fname', `lastname` = '$lname' WHERE `teacher`.`teacher_id` = '$tea_id'";
                            $this->db->query($sql);
                        }else{
                            $sql="INSERT INTO `dvp`.`teacher` (`teacher_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('$tea_id', '$fname', '$lname')";
                            $this->db->query($sql);
                        }


                }
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what **is not right**

Comment: @Thadsanasit Peangkaew post some csv data

Comment: it not same input (alien language)

Comment: If you query the data in the table, how does it output?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Sorry, i dont understand .i just wanna output same input

Comment: Is the **database connection** established with `utf8` encoding...?! Is the CSV file *actually* UTF-8? How have you confirmed this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try this out?

```
$fromAlienLang = mb_detect_encoding($item['name'], 'auto');


mb_convert_encoding($item['name'], "UTF-8", $fromAlienLang);
```

Comment: Don't use mb_convert, it will only mask the real problem.